# Why don't languages like java or python directly convert code in machine language like C++?

Tags: java, python, programming-languages, bytecode

**Why don't languages like java or python directly convert code in machine language like C++?:**

What are the reasons for this since the fact that machine language is faster than byte code?
I'm just curious.

Comment: unfortunately this is probably not the forum for this question.... but at least in my experience you dont always(often even) need the absolute fastest solution.  trade offs of  speed for cross-platform ness, or trading speed for more readable and maintainable code

Comment: Also, as a fun aside, there's nothing preventing someone from writing a compiler that goes from Java to machine code. The JLS doesn't require that the language compile to bytecode.

Comment: Also, there is nothing preventing someone from writing a machine, the language of which is Java bytecode. In fact, ARM has created just such an instruction set for its [Jazelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle) feature.

Comment: This is **the** profound question whether to use a compiled (which gets converted to machine code) or an interpreted (e.g. python) language. Answer is you aren't always concerned with speed. Things like ability to work on multiple platforms (e.g. Java), to easily debug bits of code (by running parts of it) or what your office mates are good at also affect this choice ;) Whenever you compile something, however, it will be suitable only for that platform. This means that you need to compile and debug the same piece of code several times. With an interpreted language you don't care that much.

Comment: Oh and by the way, you can compile Python if you insist, e.g. into C (and then into machine code): http://cython.org/

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke: Cython is a subset of Python (well, a superset of a subset…), not the same language.

Comment: The Python Design and History FAQ has [an answer that's relevant here](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#can-python-be-compiled-to-machine-code-c-or-some-other-language). (Also see [the older, different answer for 2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#can-python-be-compiled-to-machine-code-c-or-some-other-language).) It doesn't directly answer the question, but it gives some useful information. Also search for Microsoft research on DLR, which discusses a lot of the issues with trying to compile dynamic languages without losing their advantages.

Comment: Of course the DLR project was about compiling the dynamic languages to an intermediate bytecode language, and then JIT-ing that bytecode to native code… but actually, both halves of that are relevant here. (And, along with the second half, the other MS and Java research that shows ways that a JIT-equipped bytecode interpreter can sometimes be _faster_ than native code.)

Comment: @abarnert True, though the parts that aren't supported are pretty obscure, as it just uses `PyObject *` and the CPython API if you don't declare types. [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/) is a better example, though it's not complete yet.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, you're right. And the fact that there are many constructs it can't execute any faster than CPython is actually a lot more important for this question than the fact that there are a few it can't execute at all, isn't it…

Comment: And that brings up another point: Right now, there is a _lot_ of Python code that will run a lot faster in PyPy (and maybe Jython and/or IronPython) than compiled Cython or Nuitka. Will that always be true? Who knows. But it's definitely a good thing that both projects (or, rather, all five projects) exist, and also a good thing that none of them are holding up Python/CPython development.

Comment: @yshavit It is required if you want to support the standard library, including custom classloaders.

Comment: @antimony You could just compile those as well, class loaders and all. I'm not saying it'd be easy, but it's technically possible. There's nothing the JVM can do that machine code can't.

Comment: @yshavit You could compile the JVM, sure, but that what people already do (Hotspot is written in C/C++ after all). The point is that anything that lets you dynamically load and execute bytecode will basically have to replicate the VM anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java, the answer is portability. Compiling to machine code would reduce the amount of available platforms capable of being written for. A virtual machine is a good solution. There's a lot more information here: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Cycle/compile.html

Comment: thats certainly an answer for Java ... Im not sure you are qualified to state that that is THE answer ... another answer is being able to do more with less lines

Comment: It would also be because, if you had to compile to a native exe, you'd need to produce an output file for every platform, and given the colourful language our senior unix dev uses when trying to get tools to compile, I'd say it would be far more difficult on some platforms then others ;)

Comment: Yes and no. The portability thing is a bit overstated. While you can now use the same compiler output on various platforms, you can't actually run said compiler output on platforms that don't have a JVM implementation. The JVM still has to be ported to each of those platforms, much like a straight-to-machine-code compiler and its standard library would have to be ported.